# In React-Router v3, must all routes be nested within a <Route> with path="/"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I ask this because I want to know if this (below) is possible and if so how should my pages look to have this work correctly?

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Root}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="404" component={Empty} />
        <Route path="about" component={About} />
        <Route path="archive" component={Archive} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="dashboard" component={_Dashboard}>
        <IndexRoute component={_Master} />
        <Route path="post" component={_Post} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/dashboard" />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Is it possible to have the routes for "/" and "dashboard" be the same level child as each other?

For layout purposes, I want all the pages nested under "/" to use the Root component's layout while all the pages nested under "dashboard" to use the _Dashboard component's layout.

**UPDATE (Solution Below)**

The issue that was making what I have above not work/possible was due to where I had my Redirect for the root level located. Following Thomas Sojka's answer solved my issue.

Here (below) is what I currently have that is working just as I need it to (the component names and paths are slightly different this time around but the overall idea and structure should be enough to show the solution).

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Root}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="404" component={Empty} />
        <Route path="about" component={About} />
        <Route path="archive" component={Archive} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="dashboard" component={_Root}>
        <IndexRoute component={_Home} />
        <Route path="404" component={_Empty} />
        <Route path="post" component={_Post} />
        <Route path="post-single" component={_PostSingle} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="404" />
    </Route>
    <Redirect from="*" to="404" />
</Router>
```

The Redirect for the root level must be the same level child as the Routes for "/" and "dashboard", as well as after/below all these Routes, to work. Where I had this Redirect located in my original question made it so that "dashboard" and any of its children could never be found.

Having the Redirect for any of the children of "dashboard" located where it is works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your 404 route at the end otherwise the /dashboard route is never found:

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Root}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='404' component={Empty} />
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='archive' component={Archive} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={_Dashboard}>
      <IndexRoute component={_Master} />
      <Route path='post' component={_Post} />
      <Redirect from='*' to='/dashboard' />
    </Route>
    <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
  </Router>
```

Comment: I feel like I ran into an issue that was probably caused or atleast related to this. I will try this out, thanks!

Comment: Following this suggestion is what solved my issue and made what I was asking for possible, thanks! Updating my original post/question to show what I currently have that works just as I need it to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, only thing is that you need to specify the child routes little differently

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Root}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="/404" component={Empty} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/archive" component={Archive} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={_Dashboard}>
        <IndexRoute component={_Master} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/post" component={_Post} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/dashboard" />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: It will not work without `routes` property for react-router v3, and you can't provide several adjacent Route tags without root Route element

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for React-Router v3 you have to provide `routes` property like this

```
const routes = (
    // Your routes
);

<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```

If you don't, then you will get error

> Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes

If you just separate routes for "/" and "dashboard" without root Route tag, it will give you error

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

The proper way to define your routes

```
const routes = (
    <Route path="/">
        <Route path="" component={Root}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="404" component={Empty} />
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="archive" component={Archive} />
            <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="dashboard" component={_Dashboard}>
            <IndexRoute component={_Master} />
            <Route path="post" component={_Post} />
            <Redirect from="*" to="/dashboard" />
        </Route>
    </Route>
);

<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```

Comment: I followed https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md for how to configure some of what I have and they wrap the Routes in the Router element instead of using the "routes" property to take in a const. Seems to work fine for me with what I currently have (not with the nested structure like in my original post).

Comment: Hm, I've tested locally with v3.0.2, it gives me error if I don't provide `routes` property. Anyway, it works for you, ok, what about nesting Route tags as I described, did it work for you?